# Compressing all files inside linux kernel rpm package

Tags: makefile, compilation, linux-kernel, rpmbuild, xz

My current linux system has kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 installed and now am trying to upgrade it to **kernel-5.5.7** which is the latest stable release.

Post compiling the tarball for kernel-5.7.7 obtained from https://www.kernel.org/ I obtained an rpm which is close to 590M in size. The previous rpm that my existing machine uses is mere 150M.

I used https://linuxhint.com/compile-linux-kernel-centos7/ for compilation.

On observing file content, I see all files in the 3.10.0.693 rpm are compressed with .xz extension whereas this compression was not present in my newly compiled rpm.

I tried a CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ=y and CONFIG_DECOMPRESS_XZ=n options before starting `make binrpm-pkg` but yet the rpm size is huge.

Can anyone suggest what flags to use and where to use them? Shall I edit the .config file or the Makefile for each file within the rpm to be compressed with .xz extension.

Following is just for reference

```
rpm -ql kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 | grep '.xz' | wc -l
2406

rpm -qpl kernel-5.7.7-1.x86_64.rpm | grep '.xz' | wc -l
0
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by default the DEBUG KERNEL is enabled in the kernel tarball.
Generated the config using `make menuconfig` and edited the .config file and changed `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y to CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=n` and executed `make binrpm-pkg`.

The rpm generated was of 57MB which is very much acceptable.